# How to decrypt a string with known key and a IV in java?

Tags: public-key-encryption, initialization-vector

I have a string that is encrypted in c#.net which I have to decrypt in java using a key and a IV provided by the client. Used algorithm is AES.

I have tried few things. The key looks something like

```
key = "QWEEqweASDreefERTfdf45fefdWERfsdf34fedfdwn5=" //length 44 bytes
iv  =  "nkfghER24dfdfdf56YUIgH==" // lenght=24 bytes
```

When I use this with Cipher class with algorith `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`
passing the above key to `Secretkeyspec` class it says invalid key lenth 44 bytes

I am not able makeout whats wrong with the key. Tried all suggested solutions for few days nothing works. Can some one help please? Thank you.

Comment: Got it working!:-)
The problem was key and IV are base64 encoded. i decoded it using
BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer. and installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 as i use 256 bits for encryption and hurray it worked thanks for all replies and suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

Use java native for C# code.
First write C# code for decrypt the key.
and calling the code in java using native.
for reference 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java